# fortran vector-valued function gives bus error

Tags: fortran

The following program gives me a bus error... any ideas why?

```
  program main
  integer, parameter :: n = 3
  integer, dimension(n) :: out

  out = rep(1,n)
  print *, (out(i), i=1,n)

  end program

  function rep(x,n)
  integer :: x
  integer :: n
  integer, dimension(n) :: rep

  do i=1,n
     rep(i) = x
  enddo

  end function
```

I think it has to do with the `integer, dimension(n) :: rep` but I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What is the error message you get? I get segfault with pgf90 and gfortran, and some bizzare error message with ifort. I'm almost sure the problem is in rep not being declared as an external function in main program, so it assumes rep is an array and not a function. But did not manage to get it to work. Also, good practice is to use implicit none throughout. It will help narrow down problems like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the interface explicit to make sure that Fortran knows what rep is when you call it. put your rep function into a module in a separate file like this:

```
  module m_rep

  contains

  function rep(x,n)

  implicit none

  integer :: x
  integer :: n
  integer :: i
  integer, dimension(n) :: rep

  do i=1,n
     rep(i) = x
  enddo

  end function

  end module
```

then use the module in your main program with the line

```
  use m_rep
```

Also, use implicit none to make sure all your variables are declared properly.

Comment: +1 it doesnt have to to a separate file though.  More modules canbe in one. Also an interface block can be used without a module.

Comment: yes, you can use an interface block as well. I did that before I learned how modules worked, it's more convoluted but it works.

Comment: An interface will work but has the disadvantage that it has to be maintained to be consistent with the procedure definition (function or subroutine).  If you change the procedure, you have to change the calls and the interface.  If you put the procedure in a module, the interface is known to any program or procedure that "uses" that module and consistency checking  between the procedure and call is obtained with no further effort by the programmer.  In this case, if you change the procedure, you only have to change the calls.  Less work and less chance of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks - for vector/array-valued functions, this is the only method that will work it seems (with `gfortran`). I was not able to include the module above my program in the same file. The `interface` block also seems useful and will perhaps invoke next time.

Answer (score 1):

Still not exactly an answer to your question, but maybe a subroutine call instead of function will work for you:

```
program main
implicit none
integer :: i
integer, parameter :: n = 3
integer, dimension(n) :: out

call repeat(1,3,out) 
print *, (out(i), i=1,n)

end program

subroutine repeat(x,n,y)
implicit none
integer :: i   
integer,intent(in) :: x,n
integer,dimension(n),intent(out) :: y

do i=1,n
  y(i) = x
enddo

endsubroutine
```

Hopefully someone will come up with an answer for your function. The problem I am having with it is that Fortran won't let you do something like:

```
integer,external :: rep(n)
```

Comment: Thanks - this is old-school f77 style (except with modern declarations) - I thought about it but I really wanted to make it a function.