# Return type mismatch of function

Tags: fortran

I want to diagonalize a complex matrix in fortran90 with a function. This is the function I use

```
!==========================================================================
function inv(A,n)
  Implicit none
  integer :: n  
  complex*16, dimension(n,n):: A
  complex*16, dimension(n,n):: inv
  complex*16,allocatable,dimension(:)::WORK
  integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::IPIV
  integer i,j,info,error

  allocate(WORK(n),IPIV(n),stat=error)
  if (error.ne.0)then
    print *,"error:not enough memory"
    stop
  end if


  call ZGETRF(n,n,A,n,IPIV,info)
  if(info .eq. 0) then
    write(*,*)"succeded"
  else
   write(*,*)"failed"
  end if

  call ZGETRI(n,A,n,IPIV,WORK,n,info)
  if(info .eq. 0) then
    write(*,*)"succeded"
    inv=A
  else
   write(*,*)"failed"
  end if
  !deallocate(A,IPIV,WORK,stat=error)
  !if (error.ne.0)then
  !  print *,"error:fail to release"
  !  stop
  !end if
end function inv
```

and I simply call it with

```
Wmattemp=inv(Wmattemp,nsit)
```

where its type is

```
complex*16, allocatable :: Wmattemp(:,:)
```

But I obtain this error when I compile with

```
gfortran -fdefault-real-8 code.f90 -llapack

code.f90:217.19:

       Wmattemp=inv(Wmattemp,nsit)
               1
 Error: Return type mismatch of function 'inv' at (1) (INTEGER(4)/COMPLEX(8))
 code.f90:217.16:

       Wmattemp=inv(Wmattemp,nsit)
            1
Error: The reference to function 'inv' at (1) either needs an explicit INTERFACE or the rank is incorrect
```

II'm not a fortran expert so I cannot find what is the problem.

Now I added to the main program

```
complex*16, allocatable :: inv(:,:)
```

but I obtain this error

```
code.f90:217.13:

       A=inv(Wmattemp,nsit)
             1
Error: Array index at (1) must be of INTEGER type, found COMPLEX
```

Comment: Almost certainly you haven't declared inv at the CALLING site, i.e. not in this piece of code but where inv is invoked. Can you also show that piece of code, with all the declarations?

Comment: I added the declaration of inv but now I obtain another error

Comment: I suggest that you place your procedures (subroutines and functions) into one or more modules and `use` those modules.  Then you won't have to declare the functions. This make make the interfaces known to the compiler, which can then check argument agreement.  If you write an interface, then you have three things to change if the function changes: the function, the call(s), the interface.  With modules, only two: the function and the call(s)

Comment: examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395124/fortran-vector-valued-function-gives-bus-error/8396034 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511711/computing-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors-in-fortran-90

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using modules, you need to declare the return value of the function `inv` in the main program using an interface block:

```
program main
! [...]
interface inv
  function inv(A,n)
    integer :: n  
    complex*16, dimension(n,n):: A
    complex*16, dimension(n,n):: inv
  end function
end interface
! [...]
Wmattemp=inv(Wmattemp,nsit)
```

Comment: You are right but it is better not to mix the terms "explicit interface" and "interface block". It leads to confusions what the advanced passing mechanisms actually require (i.e. not an interface block).